# Particular solution of Schrodinger equation, satisfying time dependent boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples, boundary-value-problem, parabolic-pde

I am considering the Schrodinger equation on $[0,1]$:
$$iu_t=-u_{xx}$$
I am looking for a particular solution $u(x,t)$ which satisfies the boundary condition $$\cos(t)\cdot u_x(0,t)=\sin(t)\cdot u(0,t)$$
(which is not $u=0$)

I know that this is an undetermined problem (since I am missing a boundary condition at $x=1$ and also an initial condition). But for my case, I only care about finding one particular solution which satisfies the condition above (and not some general solution), so I don't impose any more restrictions.

More generally (perhaps this will be easier), I am interested in an example of a solution to the Schrodinger equation such that its boundary condition at $x=0$ at time $t=0$ is Neumann ($u_x=0$), and at some other time it is Dirichlet ($u=0$), like in the example above, with $t=\pi/2$. My only restriction is that I want the ratio $u_x/u$  at the boundary to be real valued for all $t$ (such that $u\neq0$). If you can set it so that the same boundary condition also holds at $x=1$ - that would be even better.

Does anyone have an idea on how to find such an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Such a solution will be hard to find, because it cannot be separable - see that if $u(t,x)=p(t)q(x)$ that your BC equation would imply $\cos(t)p(t)~q'(x)=\sin(t)p(t)~q(x)$, clearly an impossibility. I think you will have to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: @K.defaoite I agree - this difficulty with nonseparability is exactly why I asked the question. I am hoping that since I did not give too many restrictions on the other boundary and initial condition, then somebody might be able to make a "smart guess" for a solution (even just for the second problem - the sine/cosine is not that important to me). Sadly, for my needs I am looking for an actual solution (not numerical). Also, I am not very familiar with numerical theory for such problems with time dependent boundary conditions.

Comment: The original problem has the trivial solution $u=0$, but that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Aruralreader Of course. I'll add that to the post, but I'm naturally looking for a nontrivial solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution:

$$u(x,t) = \cos(x)e^{-it} + i \sin(x)e^{-it} + \cosh(x)e^{it} - i\sinh(x)e^{it}$$

Each term is independently a solution to the stated differential equation.

Note that it isn't exactly true that the problem isn't separable (I may be bending the definition here...). The *differential equation*'s separable qualities are unaffected by your *boundary condition*: you can still use separation of variables to form elementary solutions to the differential equation. Normally before going further, one uses the boundary conditions to discard/constrain most of the elementary solutions, which is the part we can't perform here (at least not through the normal procedure).

By not discarding any elementary solutions, I was able to find the above solution which uses a superposition of both the sinusoid and hyperbolic sinusoid solutions.

Comment: A very nice solution.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, great point about (non)separability too.